# jQuery split only words that do not have specific class

Tags: jquery, text

I have the following markup:

```
<div id ="selectable1">
<span id="layer6">
here are some words that needs to be splited
<span class="good">this should not be splitted<span>
this should be splitted
<span class="good">and this should not be spited<span>
</span>
</div>
```

I am trying to write a function that will split only the words that do not have class "good".
I am using this:

```
var words = $("#selectable1 span.cica").text().split(" ");
var text = words.join("</span><span class='drag col'>  ");
$("#selectable1 span.cica").html("<span class='drag col'>" + text + "</span>");
```

...but this is splitting all my words and I need the "good" class not to be splitted and not to be added to the var text - join.

I hope that I had explained well what I want to do here, I know that this can be confussing.

Thanx for your help

Comment: *splitted = 'split'. Just as a general point.

Comment: You're reading `text` and then setting `html`. If there is a `<` or `&` in that text you've got an error, and likely XSS security problems. Avoid working on HTML strings. For each word, create a new `span` and set its `text` to the word.

Comment: Thanx Bobnice, I will see if I can do this.

Answer (score 4):

Update based on comments.  Since you'r wrapped in a span, the selector is going a bit crazy, do this instead:

```
var span = $("#selectable1>span.cica").clone();
span.find(".good").remove();
var words = span.text().split(" ");
var text = words.join("</span><span class='drag col'>  ");
```

Comment: I've tryed this:
var words = $("#selectable1 span.cica:not(.good)").text().split(" ");
var text = words.join("</span><span class='drag col'>  ");
$("#selectable1 span.cica").html("<span class='drag col'>" + text + "</span>");

But it does not work.
I've made an edit to my source adding the line that actually execute the variabiles

Comment: @Mircea - What's the `.cica` for?

Comment: @Nick there are several spans in that #selectable container. The one that is active have the class .cica. When someone clicks on a span it becomes active and gets class cica

Comment: your code should work but this code just takes all the text including the "good" class one:
$("#selectable1 span.cica").html("<span class='drag col'>" + text + "</span>");

Comment: @Mircea - I see what you mean now, I updated the answer, you should be all set now.

Comment: @Nick, it does keep the good classes but duplicates the whole text. Its better and I may be able to fix it. I am really sorry but I have to go out for 2 hours. I will post the solution, if I can fix it, later on today.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
var words = $("#selectable1 span:not(.good)").text().split(" ");
var text = words.join("</span><span class='drag col'>  ");
```

That might work...